# Adding sublayer to view.layer changes the frame position?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation, calayer

I'm adding a `CALayer` as a sublayer to a `UIView`'s `layer` property as follows:

```
_graphicLayer = [[GraphicLayer alloc] init];
        self.bounds = _graphicLayer.bounds;
        _graphicLayer.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds));
        [self.layer addSublayer:_graphicLayer];
```

As you can see, I change the position of _`graphicLayer` to account for the centered `anchorPoint`. I'm noticing after I add this sublayer, that it's changing the views `frame` to `(-self.bounds.width / 2, -self.bounds.height / 2)`. Why is this happening? If I change the position of _`graphicLayer`, I thought that was only relative to its parent view. Why would it affect the views `frame` property? (and I don't want to have to adjust the anchorPoint of either the views layer property or `_graphicLayer`).

Answer (score 2):

You're currently doing

```
self.bounds = _graphicLayer.bounds;
```

which would change the view's (self's) frame as it would change the width and height. Maybe you meant to do :

```
_graphicLayer.bounds = self.bounds;
```

See here about how bounds affect the frame:[Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/bounds)